# separating names from a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My column looks like this

```
Fullname
--------------------------
Joseph Davis Matthews
Leonardo Maser Davidson
Leo Garces S. Yu
```

I want to separate the last name for easy searching so I do this substring function

```
RIGHT(dbo.Fullname, 40) as lastname
```

My query result shows:

```
Lastname
---------------------------
Joseph Davis Matthews
Leonardo Maser Davidson
Leo Garces S. Yu
```

The source column is `char(40)`, is there an easier script to separate the last name from the column?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: If the column is 40 characters long, and you're doing a `RIGHT(..., 40)` - you're getting the whole column back....

Comment: How do you know which parts make up the last name?? How about `Francisco de Montoya` - or `Jean-Pierre de Vigier` or `Poul van de Graaf` - how do you know where the first and last names are "separated" ? This is next to impossible to do without user intervention, e.g. some biomechanical parsing :-)

Comment: I was thinking of using the space before the last name as the marker for the last name

Comment: i also encountered issue with that qualifier

Answer (score 2):

As @marc_s has mentioned you are assuming that the lastname is just the last word. Assuming this is what you want, you can get the last word of a string by doing the following:

```
declare @names as table
(
    name varchar(40)
)

insert into @Names values ('Joseph Davis Matthews')
insert into @Names values ('Leonardo Maser Davidson')
insert into @Names values ('Leo Garces S. Yu')


SELECT RIGHT(name,
        COALESCE(
            NULLIF(
                CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name)) - 1,
                -1),
            LEN(name)))
FROM @names
```

But again, it assumes that everyones last name is only 1 word, which is an incorrect assumption